# awk command variable NF not working on NULL input

Tags: bash, shell

I run my safe shell script to make sure a binary is running

to check a binary is running I do following command

```
pidof prog.bin | awk '{print NF}'
```

is some system it gives me 0 when binary not running 
and 
in some systems it gives me NULL(nothing)

I can check the NULL using -z option but why awk command acting this way ??

Comment: because there is actually no output from pidof, there is no line ending to match, which means that awk is free not to process any line match commands because there are no lines to match. You can use `awk 'END { print NF }'`, which will print the NF at the end of run, and if there were no matches should always print out 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `pidof` you can use:

```
pgrep -qf prog.bin
```

And check its exit status.

As per `man pgrep`:

```
-f    Match against full argument lists.  The default is to match against process names.
-q    Do not write anything to standard output.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this,

```
if [ `pidof 'NetworkManager'` ]; then
   echo "Running"
else
   echo "Not Running"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this sort of thing (undefined variables) in `awk` is like this:

```
echo hi | awk '{print a}'
```

compared with:

```
echo hi | awk '{print a || 0}'
0
```

Answer (score 1):

**One Liner for If else**

**`[[ $(pidof 'NetworkManager') ]] && echo "Running" || echo "Not Running"`**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pidof prog.bin | awk '{ if (NF!=0) print NF }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some tests with awk and NF:

```
$ # regular line of input
$ echo foo | awk '{print NF}'
1

$ # empty line
$ echo | awk '{print NF}'
0

$ # a word on input with no newline
$ printf "%s" nonewline | awk '{print NF}'
1

$ # no input, not even a newline
$ printf %s | awk '{print NF}'

# no output from awk
```

I suspect the `pidof` case is the last: not even a newline. To force a newline:

```
echo $(pidof prog) | ...
printf "%s\n" "$(pidof prog)" | ...
```